# Calculate Power and Logarithmic Regression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to calculate Logarithmic, Power Regression points(Trend line) for my array [X, Y] values  below here using java script. Example:

```
X: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Y: [10, 40, 35, 50, 55, 65]
```

I referred more sites. But they are only given formula and its description. There is no example how to calculate X,Y values using that equation. Any one please help me on how to calculate Logarithmic, Power Regression.

Thanks,
Bharathi

Comment: if you're interested in using plugins you can take a look at [regressionjs](https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js)

Comment: Thank you. But i need to implement the code with my source